# Python: multiplying fixed array by element wise second array

Tags: python, numpy

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,11)
b = np.arange(1,11)
b[:] = 0
b[3] = 10
b[4] = 10
print(a, b)
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10] [ 0  0  0 10 10  0  0  0  0  0]
```

I am attempting to multiply b by element-wise a-array such that my resulting array is the following:

```
[0 0 10 30 50 70 90 110 130 150]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If what you mean is Hadamard product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices) 
then you get it simply using `a * b`. However, for your values of `a` and `b`, the product is `[ 0,  0,  0, 40, 50,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]` rather than whay you specified as expected output, so I think clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the [`convolution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of both arrays:

```
np.convolve(a,b)[:len(a)+1]
# array([  0,   0,   0,  10,  30,  50,  70,  90, 110, 130, 150])
```

Comment: This is correct. I was mistaken on element wise multiplication. Thank you @yatu.

Answer (score 0):

Elementwise multiplication of b with a shall give you [0,0,40,50,0,0,0,0,0,0] and not what you have stated.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken. Solution to my problem solved above using np.convolve. Thank you for responding.